# Powershell parameter passing to function

Tags: function, powershell, argument-passing

I'm facing with an annoying problem: my script seemingly doesn't pass any argument to a function I've defined.

```
$server = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'

Function Get-WorkingDirectory([string]$address)
{
    #echo $address

    $content = Get-Content -path C:\....\file.txt 
    $content -contains $address
} #end Get-WorkingDirectory function



if(Get-WorkingDirectory $server)
{
    echo "works"
}
else
{
    echo "error"
}
```

It is stuck on "works". If I try to echo address in the function, it is empty.
What the heck I'm doing wrong?! I know this is a pretty noobish question, but I tried everything I found on the net.
Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: The code you posted works just fine for me.

Comment: What do you mean by `it is stuck on "works"`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the if condition is true, then it echoes "works", also if there is no evaluation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` is an alias for `Write-Output` but as you are using the output of the function in the `if` statement, nothing gets shown.

For testing purposes, use `Write-Host` in this instance to show the variable being passed correctly.

```
$server = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'

Function Get-WorkingDirectory([string]$address)
{
    write-host "$address using write host"
} #end Get-WorkingDirectory function


if (Get-WorkingDirectory $server) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Output of `Get-WorkingDirectory` is shadowed by `if` statement.

Try to use it without `if` and you'll see that argument is passed correctly. For example,

```
$server = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'

Function Get-WorkingDirectory([string]$address)
{
    Write-Host $address
} 

Get-WorkingDirectory $server
```

Address is printed well